# JSON file cannot be found when running a release's binary, but it is found when running with `iex -S mix phx.server`

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

When running the following, everything works nicely:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/absolute/path/to.json \
MIX_ENV=prod \
DATABASE_URL=... \
SECRET_KEY_BASE=... \
HOST=localhost \
PORT=80 \
iex -S mix phx.server
```

However, when generating an Elixir release with `mix release`:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/absolute/path/to.json \
MIX_ENV=prod \
DATABASE_URL=... \
SECRET_KEY_BASE=... \
HOST=localhost \
PORT=80 \
mix release
```

(`iex -S mix phx.server` is replaced with `mix release` and the rest is the same)

And running it via: `_build/prod/rel/app/bin/app start`

I'm getting the following error:

```
0:24:29.781 [info] Application goth exited: Goth.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: Goth.Config
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (RuntimeError)  Failed to retrieve project data from GCE internal metadata service.
                   Either you haven't configured your GCP credentials, you aren't running on GCE, or both.
                   Please see README.md for instructions on configuring your credentials.
            (goth 1.2.0) lib/goth/config.ex:182: Goth.Config.determine_project_id/2
            (goth 1.2.0) lib/goth/config.ex:73: anonymous fn/2 in Goth.Config.load_and_init/1
            (elixir 1.11.2) lib/enum.ex:1403: anonymous fn/3 in Enum.map/2
            (stdlib 3.13.2) maps.erl:233: :maps.fold_1/3
            (elixir 1.11.2) lib/enum.ex:2197: Enum.map/2
            (goth 1.2.0) lib/goth/config.ex:71: Goth.Config.load_and_init/1
            (stdlib 3.13.2) gen_server.erl:417: :gen_server.init_it/2
            (stdlib 3.13.2) gen_server.erl:385: :gen_server.init_it/6
```

This error means that the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/absolute/path/to.json` part did not work as expected. The JSON file cannot be found, for some reason.

I can guarantee that the JSON file exists and it seems that it's just not accessible from the release.

Does anyone know why the JSON file cannot be found when running the app from the release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runtime configuration for releases is done with `config/runtime.exs` (`config/releases.exs` before `v1.11`) and is discussed in the documentation [here](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Release.html#module-runtime-configuration).